# Styling and Annotating Source Code in InkScape

Tags: inkscape, text, resource-recommendations

I am creating a PDF document in which I need to include some annotated, syntax-highlighted source code. The individual code snippets should be PDF files with selectable text, so no .png or .jpg images. Some examples of how I would like the result to look like are at the end of this question.

As I have no graphics design experience, I am unsure which route to take. I tried to recreate something similar using **Inkscape**, but the process of syntax-highlighting is tedious (can you paste styles in Inkscape, similar to, say, MS Word?)

I am looking for recommendations on tools/workflows to layout source code and add annotations afterwards.

[image: Code example by Görtler et al. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.12536.pdf)]

Taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.12536.pdf

[image: Code example by Kim et al.]

Taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.08314.pdf

Comment: I just used Powerpoint rather than learning new  tools, worked as well.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, fsperrle! Have you already tried specific tools like LaTeX [listings package](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880508/source-code-annotation-tool))? Else (not tried), there are [LibreOffice extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/1525126/how-to-get-code-block-with-syntax-highlighting-into-libreoffice-writer): you can format your code, add your notes and export as PDF.